# Piwigo - cannot connect to server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm pretty new with Docker and Piwigo. I cloned a github repository which is https://github.com/moritzheiber/piwigo-docker. I followed the instruction and make the 2 commands with the exact code and there is an error

```
$ docker build -t piwigo-docker ./
$ docker-compose up -d
```

I would like to know why there is an error it saying **Cannot connect to server**.
All the field, I putted **piwigo** as username, password and database like this image

How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found the solution, all you have to do is get the hostname of your database with `hostname -i` and paste it here

[image]